# How to make variable from an array

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using an array like below and I'm using "category" variable after that without problem.

```
var category = resources.getStringArray(R.array.**main_menu**)
```

My question is, how can I make a variable "main_menu"?
There are other arrays also exist and I want to send their names as a varible in this line?

I tried the code below, but surely it's not working, because it's text and "getStringArray" expecting Int.

```
var **text** = R.array.main_menu
var mainCategory = resources.getStringArray(**text**)
```

Comment: So, you want to get string array by name of it?

Comment: Yes,  there are 10 other arrays exist, so I want to send these arrays to this line.

Comment: Ok, according to my understanding, I put answer. You can check out.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: @Natig, I'm trying to reach that "getPackageName" inside recyclerview's "onBindViewHolder" method, but it doesn't worked in there. Doesn't accept. Do you know how to reach from there?

Comment: You can try `context.getPackageName()`. You can use same context which you use to get `resources`.

Comment: That also worked, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method, you can get the integer id of your resource. That method accepts three parameters:

- Name of the resource as string
- Type of the resource, which is in your case `"array"`
- Package name

By using the resource id returned from `resources.getIdentifier(arrayName, "array", getPackageName())`, you can get array.

Here is full code:

```
var arrayName = "main_menu"
val resId = resources.getIdentifier(arrayName, "array", context.packageName)
var mainCategory = resources.getStringArray(resId)
```